# Android Custom Camera

Tags: android

I am looking to create a custom camera in Android. I have gotten alot of help from [here](https://github.com/whatsthegoss/SimpleCamera)
The problem is that the image preview orientation seems distorted. When the phone is in portrait mode, the image is been drawn in Landscape ? This is not the normal look and feel
Here is the code from the library. Could someone please help me

```
package com.whatsthegoss.simplecamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener{

    private static final String EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleCamera";
    private Camera mCamera;
    private boolean mPreviewRunning;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private Button mButtonCapture;
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
            final Bitmap a=Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 10,10,30, 60);
            final File file = new File(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIR, "ic_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            try {
                final FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                a.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);

                if (outstream != null) {
                    outstream.flush();
                    outstream.close();
                }

                // Update media gallery
                updateMediaGallery();


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           

            // Restart camera preview
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mButtonCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        mButtonCapture.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Create the necessary directories
        File storagePath = new File(EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIR);
        storagePath.mkdirs();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {


        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        final Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        final Camera.Size size = sizes.get(sizes.size()-2);

        final List<Camera.Size> pictureSizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        final Camera.Size pictureSize = pictureSizes.get(pictureSizes.size()-2);

        params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        params.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);

        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mCamera.startPreview();

        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mCamera.stopPreview();

        mPreviewRunning = false;

        mCamera.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.button_capture:
            mCamera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);                  
                }
            });

            break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is used to notify the media gallery that there is a new image
     * 
     */
    private void updateMediaGallery() {

        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIR)));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

adapted code from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29):

```
private void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Comment: where do i call this function

Comment: I call it after `Camera.open()`

Comment: The preview is fine, but the image is still rotated ? Can that be fixed too ?

Comment: sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIR))); thows SecurityException